# Закрытие открытого Toggle при запуске второго

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы открытый Toggle закрывался, при запуске второго?

При клике на ссылку с классом splLink, "открывается" блочный элемент splCont. Как сделать так, чтобы при открытии другого splCont, открытый ранее splCont закрывался?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.splLink').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().children('div.splCont').fadeToggle('fast');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Acht88, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@KaZaца](/users/10548/kaza%D1%86%D0%B0)](/users/10548/kaza%D1%86%D0%B0), не совсем "просто". В вашем примере, скрываться блоки будут, но **.fadeToggle()** не будет работать для текущего блока.

[[@Acht88](/users/10879/acht88)](/users/10879/acht88), не знаю вашу структуру, но могу предположить, что ссылка с классом "splLink" и блок с классом "splCont" - родственные элементы. Если это так, то записать можно следующим образом:

```
$('.splLink').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var curBlock = $(this).siblings('.splCont');
    $('.splCont').not(curBlock).hide();
    curBlock.fadeToggle('fast');
});​
```

Проверить работу [можно тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/C53B8/1/).

Comment: Спасибо! Вот так работает как хотелось

Answer (score 0):

Просто.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.splLink').click(function(){
$('div.splCont').hide();//прячем все
$(this).parent().children('div.splCont').fadeToggle('fast');
return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Да,спасибо. Но в таком случае возникает другая проблема. Теперь не закрывается открытый splCont, при повторном клике по splLink.

Буду признателен за помощь с комментарием.